# getting a specific dateformat in javascript

Tags: javascript

how can I get this format in javascript:

```
Saturday,September 21,2013
```

I did this

```
var date= new Date();
 var d= date.getDate();
```

but all I am getting is 21 wish is the number of the day

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) library to effectively work with date and time in JavaScript.

```
var date,
    dateString;
date = new Date();
dateString = moment(date).format('dddd, MMMM, DD, YYYY');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/P7ZWN/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

```
var d = new Date();

d.getDate()      // returns the number of the day
d.getMonth()     // returns the number of the month (starting from 0)
d.getDay()       // returns the number of the day in the week
d.getFullYear()  // returns the full year, i.e. 2013
```

In order to use month and day names you can easily write a convertion function:

```
function nameOfDay(dayNumber) {
    return [
        'Sunday',
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday'
    ][dayNumber];
}
```

and a similar one for the months.

(or maybe, if that functionality is very used in your application, you can use an extern library like [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/))